# difficulty in making query for this in c# linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two records in my view in SQL  [image]

Now I have to show one record in my grid in which ledgername **xxx xxx(1685)** has minimum time in **TimeIn** and maximum time in **TimeOut** I have the following things..

Comment: Please provide more information.

Comment: First - what have you tried? Second - what if neither of records has both min TimeIn AND max TimeOut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your brief question I will give a couple of pointers: [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx), [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx), [Min](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.min.aspx), [Max](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.max.aspx)